# C# ChromeDriver: javascript error: unhandled object

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to run a simple scenario in C# with ChromeDriver.

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.Version, "latest", true);
chromeOptions.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, "WIN10", true);
chromeOptions.AddArgument("-args --disable-print-preview");

Driver = Driver ?? new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

IWebElement element = Driver.FindElement(By.Name("elemet id"));
element.SendKeys("some value");
```

**

```
javascript error: unhandled object
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.100)
```

**
I'm getting the error:

```
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementByName(String name)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<Name>b__0(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
   at TestSelenium.Program.SetValue(String name, String value) in D:\Projects\local-repo\Selenium\TestSelenium\TestSelenium\Program.cs:line 69
```

I'm using chrome: 76.0.3809.100 and latest webdriver.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using chromedriver 76.0.3809.68
 https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=76.0.3809.68/ ?

Comment: @RahulL, yes I'm using chromedriver 76.0.3809.68

Comment: Try with chromedriver 76.0.3809.126 https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/76.0.3809.126/notes.txt They have fixed some bugs related to  serializing and deserializing JavaScript objects